# Batch Update a List of Record Entitiy Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, windows-services

I have a list of updated objects. And I tried to update all records with only one database call.(one context.SaveChanges() command). This programme runs inside a windows service. My problem is instead of updating I am multiplicating all records on the database and adding duplicates. Following is my code.

```
//adding the list of updated customer objects to the list
context_CLTUS.Customer_Updates.AddRange(list.customerUpdateList);
foreach (var j in list.customerUpdateList) 
{
    //calling entity state modify for each record
    context_CLTUS.Entry(j).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
//save updated list in one db call.
context_CLTUS.SaveChanges();
```

I cannot clarify why all records are duplicating instead of updating. Could you please explain and help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: only thing you need here is context_CLTUS.SaveChanges(); remove rest of things

Comment: What happens if you remove the `AddRange` call?

Comment: Removing `AddRange` worked for me thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

You can try these solutions :

1. Swap update operation in a TransactionScope.
2. Set Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false.
3. Try [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net), a high-performance enhancement
   library.

Comment: Tried Entity Framework Plus for the first time , Saved my time! thank you!

Comment: @thilanka1989 sorry for my misunderstanding, and in your case, maybe the comments above are easier, thanks for your vote too.